# Проблемы с кодировкой в oscommerce на некоторых страницах?

Tags: php

В магазине, при переключении на другой язык, на главной странице, все работает хорошо. Но, когда переключаю на другую страницу, допустим *поиск* или *залогиниться*, появляются крякозябры в меню шапки. Получается на одной странице с кодировкой все в порядке, а на другой уже нет. В остальных элементах страниц все корректно отображается.

Куда копать и где смотреть? Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте кодировки файлов и  выполняйте **вначале** каждого файла SQL запрос(**кодировку поменяйте** на нужную):

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, разные php-файлы сохранены в разных кодировках.

Если кодировка лейаута совпадает с кодировкой подключаемых файлов, то всё хорошо (если браузер угадает, конечно). А если не совпадает, то какая-то часть гарантированно будет отображена неверно.